# ModelCheckpoint not saving the hdf5 file

Tags: tensorflow, keras, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I am encountering a strange issue while building a speech-to-text model.

The model is trained and created, but when I try to save it as a hdf5 file, in order to reuse it for testing purposes, the operation simply does not work, and there are no errors popping up in the console…

Here is the full code:

```
import os
import librosa   
import IPython.display as ipd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile 
import warnings
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv1D, Input, MaxPooling1D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import load_model
import random

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(r'C:\Users\makra\OneDrive\Desktop\Conda\Speech-to-text\train\audio\yes\0a7c2a8d_nohash_0.wav', sr = 16000)

ipd.Audio(samples, rate=sample_rate)
samples = librosa.resample(samples, sample_rate, 8000)
ipd.Audio(samples, rate=8000)

labels=os.listdir(r'C:\Users\makra\OneDrive\Desktop\Conda\Speech-to-text\train\audio')

labels=["yes", "no", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "zero"]

all_wave = []
all_label = []
for label in labels:
    print(label)
    waves = [f for f in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\makra\OneDrive\Desktop\Conda\Speech-to-text\train\audio' + '/'+ label) if f.endswith('.wav')]
    for wav in waves:
        samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(r'C:\Users\makra\OneDrive\Desktop\Conda\Speech-to-text\train\audio' + '/' + label + '/' + wav, sr = 16000)
        samples = librosa.resample(samples, sample_rate, 8000)
        if(len(samples)== 8000) : 
            all_wave.append(samples)
            all_label.append(label)
            
le = LabelEncoder()
y=le.fit_transform(all_label)
classes= list(le.classes_)

y=np_utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=len(labels))
all_wave = np.array(all_wave).reshape(-1,8000,1)

x_tr, x_val, y_tr, y_val = train_test_split(np.array(all_wave),np.array(y),stratify=y,test_size = 0.2,random_state=777,shuffle=True)

K.clear_session()

inputs = Input(shape=(8000,1))

#First Conv1D layer
conv = Conv1D(8,13, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(inputs)
conv = MaxPooling1D(3)(conv)
conv = Dropout(0.3)(conv)

#Second Conv1D layer
conv = Conv1D(16, 11, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(conv)
conv = MaxPooling1D(3)(conv)
conv = Dropout(0.3)(conv)

#Third Conv1D layer
conv = Conv1D(32, 9, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(conv)
conv = MaxPooling1D(3)(conv)
conv = Dropout(0.3)(conv)

#Fourth Conv1D layer
conv = Conv1D(64, 7, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(conv)
conv = MaxPooling1D(3)(conv)
conv = Dropout(0.3)(conv)

#Flatten layer
conv = Flatten()(conv)

#Dense Layer 1
conv = Dense(256, activation='relu')(conv)
conv = Dropout(0.3)(conv)

#Dense Layer 2
conv = Dense(128, activation='relu')(conv)
conv = Dropout(0.3)(conv)

outputs = Dense(len(labels), activation='softmax')(conv)

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10, min_delta=0.0001) 
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

history=model.fit(x_tr, y_tr ,epochs=100, callbacks=[es,mc], batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_val,y_val))
```

Thank you very much for you assistance,

Makram

Comment: You still need to explain what is "simply does not work". The more detailed information you provide the faster you'll solve the issue.

Comment: I will suggest that you should try without the `save_best_only` option once.

Comment: It worked @PrateekBhatt ! And if I would like to extract the latest model, would you happen to know how?

Comment: I can recommend using `save_weights_only=True` option in your `ModelCheckpoint`. And use the API `model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)`. This will load the latest model weights as shown here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load.This is just a temporary solution, I think your model accuracy is not increasing and that is the reason your `save_best_only` option fails to save any model as you have put a condition that `accuracy` should increase.

Comment: Thank you @PrateekBhatt, at a first glance it seems to be working ! I will confirm and close the ticket when I am done testing the model. Yes, the accuracy does not increase consistently after every epoch, it could be the issue indeed...

Comment: I have created my comment as an answer so that other could benifit from the answer I provided. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend using `save_weights_only=True` option in your `ModelCheckpoint` callback and use the API `model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)`. This will load the latest model weights as shown [here](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load).This is just a temporary solution, I think your model accuracy is not increasing and that is the reason your `save_best_only` option fails to save any model as you have put a condition that **accuracy should increase** in your `ModelCheckpoint` callback.